# tinymce version 5: z-index:-1 in html not working

Tags: html, tinymce

I have html contain image tag with  z-index:-1 as follows,

when I load this html to TinyMCE, it does not load the back ground image.
But when I open same HTML in chrome browser, the background image is show,
how to fix this for tinyMce

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Same than @BjørnNyborg your problem is not well described. An example of code would help better understand you issue.
It might be a problem of container positionning (z-index only work on positionned element), or something incompatible with TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device - width, initial - scale = 1.0">
        <meta name="CreationDateTime" content="07 Dec 2020 16:03:21">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>HeartPicture</title>
        <meta name="ReportHeaderFile" content="Header.html">
        <meta name="ReportFooterFile" content="Footer.html">
        <meta name="ReportOrientation" content="Portrait">
        <meta name="ReportPageSize" content="Letter">
        <meta name="ReportLeftMargin" content="28">
        <meta name="ReportRightMargin" content="28">
        <meta name="ReportTopMargin" content="14">
        <meta name="ReportBottomMargin" content="14">
        <meta name="ReportViewerWidth" content="556">
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt;margin:0px;"><div class="body" style="width:556pt;">
        <div>
            <table style="width:549.38pt; border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:100%">
                <tr style="height:9.9pt; -aw-height-rule:exactly">
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:45pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.25pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">eg1;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">eg2</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">eg3</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">eg5</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3" rowspan="4" style="width:79.7pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="color:#000080">&lt;%&amp;eg6&gt;</span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="color:#000080">&lt;%&amp;eg7&gt;</span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="color:#000080">&lt;%&amp;eg8&gt;</span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="color:#000080">&lt;%&amp;eg9&gt;</span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">eg10</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="10" style="border-right:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-right:5.03pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top; -aw-border-right:0.25pt single;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">eg11</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" rowspan="10" style="width:0.6pt; border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; border-left:0.75pt solid #000000; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.03pt; vertical-align:top; background-color:#f3f3f3; -aw-border-left:0.25pt single; -aw-border-top:0.25pt single;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt">
                            <span style="font-weight:bold; -aw-import:ignore">eg12;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="10" style="width:16.8pt; border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; border-right:0.75pt dotted #000000; padding-right:5.03pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top; background-color:#f3f3f3; -aw-border-right:0.5pt dot; -aw-border-top:0.25pt single;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt">
                            <span style="font-weight:bold; -aw-import:ignore">eg13;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="10" style="width:16.7pt; height:9.9pt; writing-mode:tb-rl; border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; border-right:0.75pt dotted #000000; border-left:0.75pt dotted #000000; padding-right:5.03pt; padding-left:5.03pt; vertical-align:bottom; background-color:#f3f3f3; -aw-border-left:0.5pt dot; -aw-border-right:0.5pt dot; -aw-border-top:0.25pt single; -moz-transform:rotate(180deg); -ms-transform:rotate(180deg); overflow:hidden; transform:rotate(180deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <div style="height:9.9pt; writing-mode:tb-rl; -aw-ignore:true; overflow:hidden">
                            <p style="margin:0pt 5.65pt; text-align:center; font-size:10pt">
                                <span style="font-weight:bold">&lt;%&amp;eg14&gt;</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="10" style="width:16.7pt; height:9.9pt; writing-mode:tb-rl; border-top:0.75pt solid #000000; border-right:0.75pt solid #000000; border-left:0.75pt dotted #000000; padding-right:5.03pt; padding-left:5.03pt; vertical-align:bottom; background-color:#f3f3f3; -aw-border-left:0.5pt dot; -aw-border-right:0.25pt single; -aw-border-top:0.25pt single; -moz-transform:rotate(180deg); -ms-transform:rotate(180deg); overflow:hidden; transform:rotate(180deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <div style="height:9.9pt; writing-mode:tb-rl; -aw-ignore:true; overflow:hidden">
                            <p style="margin:0pt 5.65pt; text-align:center; font-size:10pt">
                                <span style="font-weight:bold">&lt;%&amp;eg15&gt;</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:9.9pt; -aw-height-rule:exactly">
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:45pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.25pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:9.9pt; -aw-height-rule:exactly">
                    <td colspan="3" rowspan="4" style="width:90.05pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="color:#000080">&lt;%&amp;eg,1.12&gt;</span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="color:#000080">&lt;%&amp;eg,1.12|L%&gt;</span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="color:#000080">&lt;%&amp;eg,2.12&gt;</span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="color:#000080">&lt;%&amp;eg,2.12|&gt;</span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="width:45pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.25pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:34.45pt; padding-right:5.4pt; padding-left:5.4pt; vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word;" valign="top">
                        <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt">
                            <span style="-aw-import:ignore">&#xa0;</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        
                
            </table>
            <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt; font-size:10pt">
                <span style="height:0pt; display:block; position:absolute; z-index:-1"><img src="download.jpg" width="606" height="795" alt="" style="margin-top:-615.35pt; -aw-left-

    pos:0.3pt; -aw-rel-hpos:margin; -aw-rel-vpos:margin; -aw-top-pos:0pt; -aw-wrap-type:none; position:absolute"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div></body>
    </html>

the above is the example html,
image can be replaced with any other image.
```

Comment: this is the original HTML where image with zindex=-1 is not loaded in tinyMCE